As an employer, how to deal with an employee who got cancer
We are a small company located in Canada with a dozen employees, I'm the employer. I'm seeking some advice on how to deal with an employee who just got cancer. The employee's role is essential and currently, he's the only one occupying this role and has been with us for two years.
He recently got diagnosed with cancer, and he immediately informed me about it. I like the employee and he has been good at his job, I'm very sympathetic to his diagnosis and want to support him at this time but of course, at the same time I have to take care of the company. As a short-term solution, we immediately posted a job opening to hire someone for the role because as expected the employee is taking many sick days now for appointments and they will likely increase substantially if the starts treatment.
I want to know how I can handle this. The ways I thought of are below:

Keep him as full-time employee and let him do his job as much as he can, this will be very draining on our finances and I'm not clear how it will affect the culture of the company
Let him go with a severance package, I'm not clear about the legality of this option
Ask him to take unpaid sick time off, as support from the company, we will keep paying for his insurance while at the same time, he can claim employment insurance from the government.


You need to talk to an HR advisor in your jurisdiction (assuming you don't already have someone qualified internally).

Shouldn't you first discuss this with said employee? The best course of action depends on what the employee realistically expects to happen in the coming weeks or months. There's no single "cancer", the employee might want just a couple of weeks off work and stay in touch all the time, or they might actively prefer to take half a year off.

Make sure he dont have a feeling of being needed, so he work just because you depend on him, while he would prefer not work now.

Not sure about Canada, but in Europe there would be many legal constraints about what you can do. Consulting a lawyer or just an expert on what your are required to do seems the first step before deciding what you want to do.

I don't think you have very many options. If you cannot fire him for cause, because as you describe his record, he does his job well.  You could offer a severance that satisfies his needs and wants to take care of their family, but that assumes that is what he wants.  Outside of that, until he uses all his sick leave, you're likely limited in what you can do unless having his potential eventually replacement work beside him. In reality, there is a very good chance he will pass while employed at your company.

VTC: Ultimately this comes down to making a choice. We cannot answer that for you. But I want to ask you this: Do you want to be rememembered as the Boss who moved helped a key employee in their time of need or do you want to be remembered as the Boss who discarded their employee in a time of need.

Don't you have disability insurance for your employees. These typically cover most of the sick hours for extended absences and are mandatory in many legislations (don't know about Canada).

One option:  could you find a young person that could operate as an apprentice to the employee?  The employee could train the young person, and perhaps when things get bad, that young person could fill in for the sick person.  Is something like that an option?

And the treatment can be successful resulting in an employee who is able to do their job. There have been employees with cancer who were able to do their job fully while going through treatment. Terminating such an employee would not be in the interests of the company.

My personal opinion as an exec.
Leave the decision to the employee and offer all support you and the company can afford.
Times can be hard, for employees and for companies. Loyalty and identity work both ways.
Good luck.
